getting error zsh: command not found: flutterfire
I'm developing app in flutter and did firebase configuration to my flutter app.Using IDE - VSCode, Firebase configuration for flutter project.
I'm getting error all time:

zsh: command not found: flutterfire, giving error Undefined name 'DefaultFirebaseOptions'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.dart
undefined_identifier

This is my code -
import 'firebase_options.dart';


Future<void> main() async {`enter code here`
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
        

I'm getting error all time
    logcat ==

    getting error -  zsh: command not found: flutterfire
    
         flutterfire configure
        zsh: command not found: flutterfire


follow the Homebrew installation steps -

% /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

check for % brew --version

if it produce error : zsh: command not found: brew 

then install git using cmd :

% brew install git

it may give this error again : zsh: command not found: brew

then again check for :  

% git --version

if git installed will show this : git version 2.39.3 (Apple Git-146)

then run cmd to export path : % export PATH="/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH"

print path : check this cmd

% echo $PATH

it will take few min

after that run cmd to install git

% brew install git

it will download files

you will see 

- zsh completions and functions have been installed to:
  /opt/homebrew/share/zsh/site-functions

check for version :

% brew --version

Homebrew 4.3.14

Cheers:  zsh: command not found: brew issue fixed now!


Error says that flutterfire CLI is not properly configured in your environment. As per documentation, you have to install it in this manner:
dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli

This command will add flutterfire command to your path and it will be accessible in your build.
You should also restart your IDE after that, just in case some problems with PATH.
After all that manipulations, flutterfire should be accessible from your terminal, check it like that:
flutterfire --help
A CLI tool for FlutterFire projects.

Usage: flutterfire <command> [arguments]

Global options:
-h, --help       Print this usage information.
    --verbose    Enable verbose logging.
-v, --version    Print the current CLI version.

Available commands:
  configure     Configure Firebase for your Flutter app. This command will fetch Firebase configuration for you and generate a Dart file with prefilled FirebaseOptions you can use.
  reconfigure   Updates the configurations for all build variants included in the "firebase.json" added by running `flutterfire configure`.
  update        Update the version of firebase plugins in your pubspec to the latest version and clean your workspace to ensure that everything works properly.

Run "flutterfire help <command>" for more information about a command.

Also, it's crucial to add .pub-cache to you PATH. It is usually in $HOME/.pub-cache/bin

I tried this didn't work in my case
